# How to install git only for installing plugins for rails from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to install git only for installing plugins for rails from github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the read-only subversion interface to check out the github stuff, as subversion could be more available for your system. As an example, for a project at http://github.com/einars/js-beautify you could check out it as

```
svn co http://svn.github.com/einars/js-beautify
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use portable git

http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Programming/Portable-Git.shtml