# problem when installing rails plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-tree

I'm trying to install acts_as_tree plugin, i got no error from the command line but i still get :

`undefined local variable or method`acts_as_tree' for #`

the vendor/acts_as_tree is empty and when i try install again i get :

`already installed: acts_as_tree (git://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree.git)`

i'm running rails 2.3.5 on windows with aptana 2 and instantrails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604797/how-to-install-git-only-for-installing-plugins-for-rails-from-github)